# Why I am getting an error for QQLine plot in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

While trying to draw QQ-Line plot ,I am getting the below error:

> Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...): plot.new has not been called yet
> Traceback:
>
> 1. qqline(resid(linm))
> 2. abline(int, slope, ...)
> 3. int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...)*

```
qqline(resid(linm))
```

Any clue to solve this would be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Based on the docs (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/robcbi/versions/1.1-3/topics/QQline), perhaps you should try calling `qqnorm()` before you call `qqline()`

Comment: @jared , I have called qqnorm() alrready,it doesn't helping though.Thanks Anyway

Comment: Actually It worked when I ran both of qqnorm amd qqline together(i,e in a single cell).thanks

Comment: Glad you figured it out. If possible, it would be great to answer your own question showing your solution (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), or alternatively accept @BappaDas's answer below as it looks like it's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like

```
library(mlbench)

data(BostonHousing)

#Fit the model
fit.lm <- lm(medv~.,data = BostonHousing)

#Calculate the residuals for the model
x <- residuals(fit.lm, type="deviance")

#First draw the theoretical quantile vs. residuals plot
qqnorm(x, ylab = "Deviance Residuals")

#Then add the line to that plot
qqline(x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both of you Jared_mamrot and Bappa Das are correct in your way. But I found the below code to get me out of the problem. In fact,

```
qqnorm(residuals(linm))
qqline(residuals(linm))
```

Actually, it worked when I ran both `qqnorm` and `qqline` together (i.e. in a single cell).

thanks